# source code of python inbuilt functions

Tags: python, function

I have used **type()** function in my program...

I just want to know how does Python implement this? Or where could I find the source code file that implement this function?

Comment: `type` is not only a function, it is the base class for all metaclasses of new-style classes.  See [Python's data model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) for further reading.

Answer (score 13):

The *type()* function is implemented in C.  Here's a link to the source:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0f837071fd97/Objects/typeobject.c

Answer (score 2):

### In general

`import multiprocessing

 multiprocessing.__path__

 multiprocessing.__file__`

`__path__` yields location of the library
`__file__` yields complete path of the file.

If above didn't work, you need to look into python development source code.

Regarding `type` source code, Raymond Hettinger's answer is correct.

Comment: No.  `type`, like other members of `__builtin__`, are built into the Python interpreter, and are not a separate library.

Comment: @ephemient: I din know this, I was under assumption whenever interpreter loads, builtin funcs are imported to namespace, so all builtins reside in /some/path/for/builtins/*.so